# Limit Google Maps Autocomplete to European boundaries

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using basic Google Maps autocomplete:

```
    function initAutocomplete() {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                (document.getElementById('autocomplete_1')),
                {types: ['(cities)']});
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }
```

It works totally fine, but I want to LIMIT the RESULTS to only European places. I could do it with the component Region filter but it limits me to 5 countries. Europe has 20+ countries. How to limit?

Edit: European including the UK :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a wild guess I can do using the documentation :

```js
function initialize() {
    var options = {
      bounds: myCustomEuropeBounds,
      strictBounds: true,
      types: ['(cities)']
     };

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), options);
}
```

The only thing left should be to define the bounds of Europe, which I let you find out by yourself :)

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 1):

If You would like to limit results to region Europe also will work:

```
function initialize() {
  var options = {
    region:'EU',
    types: ['(cities)']
   };

  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), options);
}
```